# Set default answer to "File Conflict" dialog during NuGet package installation

Tags: nuget

I am creating a NuGet package which requires a connection string, and would like to ensure it is added during installation. To this end I've created a config file transformation to add the string to a preexisting app.config, and a rule in my .nuspec to copy a prefabricated app.config into the project in case one doesn't exist.

Everything is working exactly as planned, however if the app.config exists I now see a "file conflict: overwrite?" dialog during installation. When this dialog appears the answer will always be no - the file will be edited by XDT if the app.config exists. Is there a way to suppress the dialog, defaulting to no? Alternatively: is there a better way to handle this?

You can recreate this by adding app.config.install.xdt and app.config files to a project's Content folder, and adding the following to your .nuspec:

```
  <files>
    <file src="Content\app.config.install.xdt" target="content" />
    <file src="Content\app.config" target="content" />
  </files>
```

Comment: Why not include a powershell script to add the connection string?

Comment: Why do you need to include the app.config? Can you not just use the .xdt transform? Including the app.config will cause NuGet to try and replace it. If you can you should just use the transform.

Comment: @Will It'd be pretty easy to handle the file copy with a PS script, but [the documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) seems to suggest that installation scripts are not supported in NuGet 3.x

Comment: @MattWard the transform is ignored if the project doesn't already contain an app.config file

Comment: "####Note: install.ps1/uninstall.ps1/content are still supported for projects using packages.config, and will be suppported going forward."  It's a cross platform thing, apparently.  If that doesn't work for you, you might drop a file called example.app.config that contains the connection string, and notify the user about the file.

Comment: @Will Good find! [Link](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html#deprecated-features) for the interested.